# Not getting any line break in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc, C# SQL Server.

I am trying to get a TextAreaFor data in controller with any line break. But don't getting the line break. It shows the space if any there exist any line break.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PickNotes, new { @class = "form-control2", @maxlength = "4000", @rows = "10", @cols = "20" })
```

I am using razor syntax to call the controller. I will store it into the the DB.

Any idea for that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the TextArea doesn't have rows or do you mean the data passed from the TextArea into the controller doesn't include any line breaks?

Comment: The TextArea have multiple rows.

Comment: Try `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PickNotes, 8, 100, new { @class = "form-control2" })`

Comment: Your data is being stored with line breaks. And if you display it in the view using `<div style="white-space: pre;">@Model.PickNotes</div>` you will see that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will submit textarea data it will not display any line break in controller. But you can display it with line break in view using any of below methods:

```
1. @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.Message).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))

OR

2. @Html.Raw(Model.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
```

Comment: How can i do that? I am trying to save the data from UI to database. I am using TextArea to give the input. Input have multiple line.

Comment: Okay.. It was to display textarea text back on the view with line breaks. Thanks.